# AWS CloudFront 502 ERROR for WordPress hosted on Siteground with Hosted Zone in Route 53 and domain registered at name.com

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

My domain (`example.com`) is registered with name.com. Domain's NS are pointed to AWS Route 53 name servers.
My WordPress is hosted at siteground and having IP address (`1.1.1.1` example) and a subdomain (`aws.example.com`) is created at siteground.

In my AWS CloudFront distribution, Origin domain is pointed to `aws.example.com` since it will not accept the IP address.

In Route 53, `aws.example.com` A record points to IP (`1.1.1.1` from siteground). And `example.com` & `www.example.com`'s A & AAA records point to AWS CloudFront distribution name (`d1111abcd8.cloudfront.net` example).

Above configuration return `502 error` for both domain name and CloudFront distribution name. (Error: CloudFront wasn't able to connect to the origin).

How can I make this configuration work while I use `example.com` as public domain with CloudFront?

**Update #1**

Application is hosted wordpress on siteground.

CloudFront configuration:

- Supported HTTP versions: HTTP/2, HTTP/1.1, HTTP/1.0
- Alternate domain names: [www.example.com](http://www.example.com), example.com
- Custom SSL certificate: Yes, issued by AWS ACM
- Origin domain: aws.example.com
- Protocol: HTTP only

No additional CF configuration

Comment: Does it work without a custom domain?  What happens if you access d1111abcd8.cloudfront.net?

Comment: d1111abcd8.cloudfront.net returns 502 error as well.

Comment: So the issue has nothing to do with the custom domain. Sadly you havn't provided any information about your CF distribution setup nor application. So its not possible to even speculate what could be wrong.

Comment: As mentioned it is WordPress hosted in siteground and CF configurations updated in the question.

Comment: @Marcin, considering this issue is with CF Origin domain setting, what are the options I have other than using a sub domain `aws.example.com` while `example.com` is pointed to CF distribution and cannot use the server IP address?

Answer (score 0):

I think CloudFront might've cached an invalid response from `aws.example.com` if the DNS changes didn't propagate by the time you created the distribution. Try creating a `/*` invalidation.

Otherwise, assuming that you are able to access your website though `1.1.1.1`, I'd:

1. Create an `A` record pointing from `aws.example.com` to `1.1.1.1`,
2. Wait until DNS changes propagate and you are able to load the website by going to `aws.example.com`, so you don't have to deal with CloudFront caching the wrong response before the DNS changes propagate,
3. Create a `CloudFront` distribution pointing to `aws.example.com` with `Alternative domain name` set to `aws.example.com`,
4. Create an `A` record pointing from `example.com` to your `CloudFront` distribution - I'd suggest using an `Alias` here:

[image: Route 53 configuration]